# Can Consul be run inside a Docker container using Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, consul, docker-for-windows

I am trying to make Consul work inside a Docker container, but using Docker for Windows and Linux containers. I am using the [official Consul Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/). The documentation states that the container must use `--net=host` for Consul's consensus and gossip protocols.

The problem is, as far as I can tell, that Docker for Windows uses a Linux VM under the hood, and the "host" of the container is not the actual host machine, but that VM. I could not find a combination of `-bind`, `-client` and `-advertise` parameters (IP addresses), so that:

- Other Consul agents on other hosts can connect to the local agent using the host machine's IP address.
- Other containerized services on the same host can query the local agent's REST interface.

---

Whenever I pass the host machines IP address in the LAN through `-advertise`, I get these errors inside the container:

> 2018/04/03 15:15:55 [WARN] consul: error getting server health from "linuxkit-00155d02430b": rpc error getting client: failed to get conn: dial tcp
>   127.0.0.1:0->10.241.2.67:8300: connect: invalid argument 2018/04/03 15:15:56 [WARN] consul: error getting server health from "linuxkit-00155d02430b": context deadline exceeded

Also, other agents on other hosts cannot connect to that agent.

Using `-bind` on that address fails - my guess is, since the container is inside the Linux VM, the host machine's address is not the container's host's address, and therefore cannot be bound.

I have tried various combinations of `-bind`, `-client` and `-advertise`, using addresses like `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`, `10.0.75.2` (addresss on the Docker virtual switch) and the host machine's IP, but to no avail.

---

I am now wondering whether this is achievable at all. I have been trying this for quite some time, and I am despairing. Any advice would be appreciated!

---

I have tried the whole process without using `--net=host`, and everything works fine. I can connect agents across hosts, and I can query the local agents REST interface from other containerized applications... Is `--net=host` really crucial to the functioning of Consul?

Comment: did you ever get this working, I am struggling with the exact same issue as you. can you share your Dockerfile/Docker command line or anything that would get me a working Docker using Windows docker with Linux Containers

Comment: I believe I dropped the `--net=host` option in the end, because I did not find a solution.

Comment: Alex I got it working in the end I should post my final example up